Execute array of callbacks with parameters
I'm trying to store callbacks that specify parameters in an array and then execute them sequentially but I don't really understand how to achieve this in JS.
What I want to do:
var callbacks = [
    doThis("foo"),
    doThat("bar")
];

function doThis(a) {
    ...
}

function doThat(b) {
    ...
}

callbacks.forEach(function(callback) {
    callback() // Expression is not callable
});


doThis("foo") calls the function. You get the result of said function, not a function reference that you can later invoke. You probably want () => doThis("foo")

Change to var callbacks = [() => doThis("foo"), () => doThat("bar")];. Currently your callbacks array contains the results of those functions execution, instead of actual functions.
